# how to use rails3-jquery-autocomplete plugin for multiple words autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have use rails3-jquery-autocomplete plugin and I am just wondering how can I use it to do multiple words autocomplete.

e.g. INPUT rails, gem
it should generate auto-list twice.

How to solve this problem?..

Comment: Can you post code that you've already tried out? and then what's wrong with the output?

Comment: Do you need to use rails plugin? I suppose it would be easier just to add jquery-ui plugin to your javascripts and setup it in javascripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rails3-jquery-autocomplete plugin? It seems that it doesn't support multiple autocomplete, you need to modify the plugin code!!
If you insist on your former ideas, follow my steps.

1. run `bundle show rails3-jquery-autocomplete` to get the plugin working directroy
2. mate /lib/autocomplete.rb
3. modify the `define_method` like this:

   ```
   define_method("autocomplete_#{object}_#{method}") do
     arr = params[:term].split(",")
     unless params[:term] && params[:term].empty?
       items = object.to_s.camelize.constantize.where(["LOWER(#{method}) LIKE ?", "#{arr[arr.size-1]}%"]).limit(limit).order(order)
     else
       items = {}
   end

   render :json => json_for_autocomplete(items, method)
   ```

   end
4. modify `autocomplete-rails.js` like this

   `function split(val) {
   return val.split(/,\s*/);
   }
   function extractLast(term) {
   return split(term).pop();
   }
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[autocomplete]').each(function(i){
       $(this).autocomplete({
           source: $(this).attr('autocomplete'),
           focus: function() {
               return false;
           },
           select: function(event, ui) {
               var terms = split( this.value );
               // remove the current input
               terms.pop();
               // add the selected item
               terms.push( ui.item.value );
               // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
               terms.push("");
               this.value = terms.join(",");
               return false;
           }
       });
   });
   });`
5. restart your server and try

!! remember you'd better backup autocomplete.rb to avoid overwrite after you run bundle install.

Good luck!

Answer (score 14):

[rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) now supports specifying a delimiter using the data-delimiter option so you no longer need to hack it:

f.autocomplete_field :tags, autocomplete_tag_business_path, :"data-delimiter" => ','

I discovered it while trying to apply the hack above and discovered it isn't necessary. Works great for me!